# Cannot get word to find "If..."

Tags: vba, ms-word

I cannot execute a find in VBA for word to find "If..."  Word doesn't seem to like finding the "If." part.  Any ideas?

```
   Sub Macro2()
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Highlight = False
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "If..."
    .Replacement.Text = "If..."
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you are using?

Comment: Word may have auto-corrected your three periods to a single "ellipsis" character in the document.  See if you can delete with a single backspace - if you can then that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are Word replaced the three periods with the single character ellipsis.

As a bonus, the ellipsis should have a space before and after it, it can be a half or thin space, but certainly a non breaking space so it won't be forced onto a new line.

Comment: OK yes so it changed it to the ellipsis, so how can/do i account for that?

Comment: The ellipsis character pastes into the VB IDE, so you can copy and paste (.Text = "If…"). Alternatively, use the character code (.Text = "If" & Chr(133)).

Comment: I'm trying this to no avail. `For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words If wrd = srchText Then If wrd.Next(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text = Chr(133) Or wrd.Next(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Text = Chr(46) Then wrd.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed Else wrd.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow End If End If Next`

Comment: It will find the If... and highlight that red, but its not find the regular "if" and changing them to yellow.  I only care about the yellow "if" words.

Comment: "Taking credit for Tim William's comment?" Not intentionally. When I started to write my answer, it wasn't there, noticing it only after I submitted mine.